# Ubuntu: Best way to set microphone volume by command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, xubuntu

I have tried:

```
aumix -i 100
```

However that only seems to get me to about 3/4 of the maximum volume when I look at the change in the Sound Preferences panel.

Here is a screenshot of Sound Preferences panel with unexpected microphone volume:

[image]

I am using Xubuntu 9.10.

Comment: Just found out that using alsactl store to save audio settings could help!

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
amixer set Capture 5%+
amixer set Capture 5%-
```

to increase or decrease the mic volume.

Comment: hmm thanks. This has the same issue though. It caps out at what it says is 21dB.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `alsamixer`. It's a simple CLI mixer for Alsa.

Answer (score 3):

With amixer you can set it with commandline

`amixer scontrols` gives you the controls you can set

`amixer sset Mic 100%` gives you the 100% of capture of your microphone

Comment: This works particularly well on Rasbian Lite, thanks. Also, if you look at the output of "amixer controls" you may see a range-- e.g. 0-35. For me "amixer sset Mic 100%" has the same effect as "amixer sset Mic 35".

Answer (score 2):

```
amixer sset 'Digital',0 120
```

This is just an example.  Replace 'Digital,0' appropriately.  120 is the mic level.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Sidjit Raput's answer](https://superuser.com/a/976281/1185493) which worked for me, you have to do:

```bash
amixer scontrols
```

... to  find the ones to put in the volume setup/boost command (from [bbs.archlinux.org > Alsa audio won't work](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200806)). Mine was `'Internal Mic Boost',0` so:

```bash
amixer sset 'Internal Mic Boost',0 120
```